# pip installing package in weird location

Tags: python, imgui

I'm trying to install `imgui` with pip with `anaconda3` All of my packages are in `anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` but when I install `imgui`, it installs it in another folder on `C:\Python39`

Which location should I keep imgui in?

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing with pip, it seems like you are installing the package from the main python installation, instead of using the virtual environment. Be sure to have your virtual environment selected when launching the command. You could usually check that if at the beginning of the line in your terminal you have the name of the virtual environment between brackets, like `(anaconda3) C:\Users\...`